# Log 4 Net does not write when published

Tags: c#, .net-core, log4net, publish

I'm using log4net on .Net Core 2.0, When running from visual studio everything logs fine, However When I publish my application (locally).  The file is Created, but No messages are written to the file.   (When run in debug and release).  Here is my configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
    <file value="./logs/ids4" />
    <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd.'txt'"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="100"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="15MB"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level App  %newline %message %newline %newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
  </root>
</log4net>
```

My AppSettings.Json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

In my startup file I configure logging like so:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();
    //...
}
```

This is not a permissions issue either because the file is still created, it's just empty.  My best guess would be it's related to the logging level? I would figure publishing in debug would fix this.

How can I get logging to work when published?

**Note** I've looked at a few other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608867/log4net-console-app-not-logging-on-publish) about this however their issue seems to be that the file was not copied to the publish directory.  Log4Net.Config is in my publish directory and is this is not the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there we're multiple `appsettings.json` and there also was `appsettings.Development.json`,

I change both of them to use:

```
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "System": "Information",
  "Microsoft": "Information"
}
```

and everything started working.